# How to scrape in Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, scrape

If you visit this site, https://www.premierleague.com/match/66686 and then press stats tab, you will see several information about the match. How am I supposed to scrape the Possession for both teams?

This did not work.

```
stats = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mainContent"]/div/section[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[3]')
stats.click()
    posHome = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//body[1]/main[1]/div[1]/section[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/section[3]/div[2]/div[2]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]')
    print(posHome.text)
    posAway = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="mainContent"]/div/section[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/section[3]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]')
    print(posAway.text)
```

Please let me know how to solve this issue and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To print the ***Possession*** for both teams you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.premierleague.com/match/66686")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Accept All Cookies']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[text()='Stats']"))).click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tbody.matchCentreStatsContainer>tr>td>p"))).text)
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tbody.matchCentreStatsContainer>tr>td:nth-child(3)>p"))).text)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  33.9
  66.1
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)